# VBA to either attach table as CSV or put in email body depending condition

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

We run monthly billing from a workbook that pulls from our SQL database and with formulas splits each client's records for that month onto a separate tab.  Each tab contains the code below (each referring to that tab's unique table), which we trigger each month to generate an email for each client showing them a list (Table642 in this example) of all the items we have produced for them in the past month.

If there is a 0 in AA1 the script won't run on that tab, if AA1 = 1 then it will. I have just updated the scripts so that if there are more than 20 rows in the table (signified by a 2 in AA1), it is added as a CSV attachment to the email instead of a table in the email body.

By default AA1 on all tabs are 0. I have a "generate emails" button on a summary tab, which when clicked turns cells AA1 on all tabs to either 1 or 2 (or stays as 0 if that tab is empty). So, the "generate emails" button triggers all the tabs to run their macros, each creating an email.

The script below works on individual tabs:  If I enter 1 in AA1 it puts the table in the email body, if I enter 2 in AA1 it attaches the table to the email as a CSV.  However when I hit the "generate emails", only the sheets with 1 in AA1 generates an email, and the sheets with 2 in AA1 are ignored.

I have checked that the formulas to change AA1 to 2 when "generate emails" are working.  And there are no errors occurring.  So for some reason the sheets that need the table attaching as a CSV are being skipped, but I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

```
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("AA1"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 1 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 2 Then
    Call Attach_CSV
    End If
End Sub


Sub Attach_CSV()

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Handler
ListObjects("Table642").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"

Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Dim CSVfileName As String
Dim wsh As Worksheet

CSVfileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("C2") & " - " & Range("B2") & ".csv"

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With wsh.Range("K1:Table642")
wsh.Range("K1:Table642").Copy
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'avoid "save prompt window"
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.SaveAs CSVfileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'set to default

Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
.To = Range("H2").Value2
.CC = "example@test.com"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = Range("C2") & " - (ID: " & Range("I2") & ") - " & Range("B2") & " Monthly Billing"
.HTMLBody = "<font size=-0> Hello " & Range("G2") & ",<br/><br/>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Please review the attached list of items that we produced from " & Range("B2") & ". <br/></br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/>Your total bill for last month is " & FormatCurrency(Range("F2")) & " (" & Range("E2") & " x " & FormatCurrency(Range("D2")) & ").</font>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/><font size=-0>Please let us know within two business days whether your records match ours. If we do not get a response within this time frame, we will invoice you shortly thereafter. If your credit card is on file and we have a pre-existing authorization, we will charge your card on file and provide you with a copy of your paid invoice." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/><br/>Thank you!</font><br/>" & vbNewLine
.Attachments.Add CSVfileName
.Display 'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
Handler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Handler
ListObjects("Table642").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
.To = Range("H2").Value2
.CC = "example@test.com"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = Range("C2") & " - (ID: " & Range("I2") & ") - " & Range("B2") & " Monthly Billing"
.HTMLBody = "<font size=-0> Hello " & Range("G2") & ",<br/><br/>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Please review the following list of items that we produced from " & Range("B2") & ". <br/></br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/>Your total bill for last month's items is " & FormatCurrency(Range("F2")) & " (" & Range("E2") & " x " & FormatCurrency(Range("D2")) & "):</font>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
RangetoHTML(Range("Table642")) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/><font size=-0>Please let us know within two business days whether your records match ours. If we do not get a response within this time frame, we will invoice you shortly thereafter. If your credit card is on file and we have a pre-existing authorization, we will charge your card on file and provide you with a copy of your paid invoice." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br/><br/>Thank you!</font><br/>" & vbNewLine
.Display 'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
Handler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function



Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim xI As Integer
Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Range("AA1")
On Error GoTo Err01
xI = Int(xRg.Value)
If xI = 1 Then
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
End If
Err01:
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried making any changes?  You can create a CSV file by copying the data to a new workbook and saving that in CSV format.  Then you can use `xOutMail.Attachments.Add` to attach that file to the mail.

Comment: Hi Tim - I have updated my question - I've got the script working on individual tabs, but the CSV attachment ones are being skipped when run in bulk

Comment: Your `Worksheet_Change` event handler checks AA1 for values of 1 and 2, but your `Worksheet_Calculate` only checks for a value of 1 ?

Comment: In `Attach_CSV` you have `On Error GoTo Handler` but no code which lets you know if there was an error..  Eg: `With wsh.Range("K1:Table642")` looks like it might raise an error.

Comment: The thing is the code works.  When I go to the sheet with 20 or more rows and enter a 2 in cell AA1, the macro runs perfectly and generates the email with CSV attachment.  The issue is that when I trigger cell AA1 to change to 2 from a different tab, the macro doesn't register it.  Despite the fact that the macro does do what it's meant to when AA1 is changed to 1 from another tab.

Comment: Damn, worksheet_calculate was AN issue.  Fixing that allows the CSV attachment macro to be triggered by a formula when I am on the specific tab testing only that tab, but I still have the issue that when I hit "generate emails", only the tabs with 1 in AA1 generate, and all the 2s (which attach CSVs to emails) are skipped

Comment: Phew finally got it working - had to specify the specific sheet name instead of activesheet in Attach_CSV so it could be triggered from other tabs